# How to return data type int** from a fuction and store it?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have written a code for solving magic square using Loubere's algorithm. I've created a function for this algorithm and I want to return a value using int** but how should i do that as  I've used 2D array in the function body, also how should i store it in main() function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std ;
int ** magicSquare ( int size )
{
int number;
int sq=size*size;enter code here
int mid=size/2;
//for array
int m=0; 

//rows
int n=mid; //columns
array[m][n]=n;
for(number=1; number<=sq; number++)
{
n++;
n=n-1;
m=m+1;
if(n==-1)
n=3;
if(m==3)
m=0;
if (array[n][m]  !=0)
n++;
array[n][m]=number;
}
int* array_rows[size]=array[size][size];    
int** p=array_rows;
return p;
}
int main()
{
int dimension;
cout<<"Enter dimension of the magic square : "; cin>>dimension;
magicSquare ( dimension );
}
```

Comment: return `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of `int**`.

Comment: You need to indent your code properly.

Comment: What do you intend to do in this line `array[m][n]=n;`?

Comment: You need to allocate an array first

Comment: there is a difference between "return a 2d array" and "return a `int**`". You want the former but your code does the latter. A pointer is not an array

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you could use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to store your data and return it properly. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using square = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

square makeMagicSquare(size_t size) {
    square magicSquare(size, std::vector(size, 0));

    // <-- Your code here
    // magicSquare[i][j] = ...;

    return magicSquare;
}

int main()
{
    square sq = makeMagicSquare(10);

    // Print it
    for (auto& row: sq) {
        for (auto& cell: row) {
            std::cout << cell << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store it as an array, you would need to change the method to return a `int[][]` instead of `int**`. They work very similarly, but there is a difference between a pointer and an array.

You can store it as a `int[][]` exactly as you would expect. Storing the magic square would like the following:

```
int[][] magicSquare = magicSquare(dimension);
```

This assigns the return value of your method to a 2D array that you will then have to free when your program ends.

Remember, the way an array works is to give the address of the head of a block of data. When you return an array, even if it is a `int[][]` you are referencing the address of a block of data. In this case, it is a block of `int` arrays. In order to access it later, you need to allocate that memory block before you can do anything with it. This means that in your `magicSquare()` method, you will need to create a `int[][]` that contains the information, and that you can pass to the `int[][]` to.

**DISCLAIMER:** you can definitely do this with pointers, but it would be easier and less likely to cause errors with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Using a `std::vector` you don't have to allocate memory or free it, and it handles potentially undefined behavior such as reading past the end of the block of data.